# Error: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id when used with composite:insertChildren

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I defined a composite component (actually a few) and when I try to re-render a component inserted with  I get the error mentioned:

```
<f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':contentFrm' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt40
```

If I simply replace:

```
<et:pageContent formId="contentFrm">
```

with

```
<h:form id="contentFrm">
<div>
```

then everything works fine

Here is the relevant code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"> 

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="styleClass" default="access-box-content alpha omega grid-12" />
        <composite:attribute name="formId" default="#{cc.attrs.id}" />
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <h:form id="#{cc.attrs.formId}">
            <div class="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}">
                <composite:insertChildren/>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

This is how I use the composite

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition id="landing" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:et="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
                template="/layout/template.xhtml"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <ui:define name="main-content">
        <et:pageTitle title="#{msg.trx_lastTrx}" />
        <et:tabBar formId="currentTrxFrm">    
            <et:tab bean="#{accountTransactionBacking}"
                    prompt="#{msg.trx_currentTrxs}"
                    reRender=":contentFrm"
                    tabId="1"
                    active="true"/>
        </et:tabBar>
        <et:pageContent formId="contentFrm">
                <et:tabContentPanel rendered="#{accountTransactionBacking.selectedTab ==1}">
                    <ui:include src="/app/summary/currentTrxRG.xhtml" rendered="#{accountTransactionBacking.selectedTab ==1}"/>
                </et:tabContentPanel>
        </et:pageContent>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

TIA

Some more tests.. using same component get's the same result.. for example the following code gives similar error (even replacing render="accountSummaryLines" with render=":accountSummaryLines")..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition id="landing" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:et="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
                template="/layout/template.xhtml"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <ui:define name="main-content">
        <et:pageTitle title="#{msg.ls_lastStatement}" />

        <et:tabBar formId="acctSummTabFrm">
            <et:tab/> 
        </et:tabBar>

            <et:pageContent formId="accountButtonsFrm">

                ....

                <et:div styleClass="accountSummaryLines" divId="lastStatementLines">
                    <ui:repeat var="row" value="#{lastStatementBacking.lines.data}">
                        <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{row}" styleClass="grid-12 lastStatementDetail"/><br></br>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </et:div>
                <et:div styleClass="access-box-footer">
                    <h:commandButton styleClass="left" action="#{lastStatementBacking.lines.prevPage}" value="#{msg.buttonPrevPage}" style="float:left;">
                        <f:ajax render="accountSummaryLines" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                    <h:commandButton styleClass="right" action="#{lastStatementBacking.lines.nextPage}" value="#{msg.buttonNextPage}">
                        <f:ajax render="accountSummaryLines" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                </et:div>
            </et:pageContent>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The only way I got this particular example working is using render="@form" like so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be found because the composite component is by itself a [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html). The *real* valid client ID would be `:idOfComposite:contentFrm` where `idOfComposite` is the (auto)generated ID of the composite component itself. If you do a *View Source* in webbrowser and locate the `<form>` in question, then you'll see it.

You need to give the composite component a fixed ID

```
<et:pageContent id="contentFrm">
```

and use exactly this ID on a plain HTML element which wraps the composite's content, e.g. `<div>` or `<span>`.

```
<composite:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.id}">
        <h:form>
            <div class="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}">
                <composite:insertChildren/>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC! this solved my issue.. I actually left the `<form id="#{cc.attrs.formId}">` since I need it for the 2 example. The only thing is I had to use this `<et:pageContent id="lastStatementPC" formId="lastStatementFrm"> ... <et:div id="lastStatementLines"> <ui:repeat var= ... </ui:repeat></et:div> ... <h:commandButton action="#{lastStatementBacking.lines.prevPage}" value="#{msg.buttonPrevPage}" style="float:left;"> <f:ajax render=":lastStatementPC:lastStatementFrm:lastStatementLines:lastStatementLinesComponent"/> </h:commandButton>` is there no shorter way.. :-) (I know,I know...@form)